# How to scroll like native android app using iScroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, scroll, touch

I'm developing a web-app for Android using iScroll. my webapp scrolls slowly my problem is, it doesn't scrolls like native app

even i used this code to increase the speed of scroller. nothing improves

```
  myScroll.scrollTo(0, -10000, .0000000000001, true);
```

and my code for vertical scrolling is

```
   var myScroll;

   function loaded() { 
myScroll = new iScroll('wrap', { 
    scrollbarClass: 'myScrollbar',
      });
  myScroll.scrollTo(0, -10000, .0000000000001, true); 

    }
  document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
```

should i do any code related to touchmove? please help me thanks